# Inline page JQuery function does not work when set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am having the strangest issue in ASP.NET CORE 1.0. My
JQuery does not work when set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production. ITS Only the inline jquery of the page. All the other jquery function works fine.

Below is my code.

```
 $(function () {

    if ($("#LeadId").val() == '') {
        $("#nextButton").addClass("disabledbutton");
        $("#divTerms").removeClass("ControlIsVisible");
    } else {
        $("#nextButton").removeClass("disabledbutton");
        $("#divTerms").addClass("ControlIsVisible");
    }

    $('#lblCheckBox').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $("#chkTerms").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked === true) {
            $('#lblCheckBox').removeClass("active");
            $("#nextButton").addClass("disabledbutton");
        }
        else {
            $('#lblCheckBox').addClass("active");
            $("#nextButton").removeClass("disabledbutton");
        }
    });

    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $("#PersonalDetail_ActualCountry").val(response.country);
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <environment names ="Development">
     <link href="~/css/min/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging, Production">
        <link href="~/css/min/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <environment names="Development">
             <script src="~/js/min/site.min.js"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment name="Staging, Production">
            <script src="~/js/min/site.min.js"></script>
        </environment>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` may be located in `<environment names="Development"> `. Could you post your `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Are your CSS classes in CustomCss? If they are then currently you are not including it in staging or production.

Comment: adem you I think am not adding scriptsection to my page scripts thats why its not working.

Comment: As @DaveWilliams pointed you need to include all required js and css files for staging and production.

Comment: That does not make sense. My bower makes a bundle min file for css and javascript. Than why do I use bundle min file?

Comment: See my answer below, you need to make sure the custom script and css are added in the bundle.

Comment: Your inline jquery needs  to be in the `@section Scripts` in the cshtml page. Otherwise  if you put it inline jquery in ajax/dynamic loaded partial pages you might get inconsistent results between browsers like the symptoms you describe

Answer (score 0):

You need to add link your css and script files in production.

This can be done either by adding directly in `_layout.cshtml`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <environment names ="Development">
        <link asp-href-include="~/css/*.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link asp-href-include="~/css/CustomCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging, Production">
        <link href="~/css/min/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Add this line -->
        <link asp-href-include="~/css/CustomCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <environment names="Development">
            <script asp-src-include="~/js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script asp-src-include="~/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script asp-src-include="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
            <script asp-src-include="~/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script asp-src-include="~/js/CustomScript.js"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment name="Staging, Production">
            <script src="~/js/min/site.min.js"></script>
        </environment>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or better in `bundlesconfig.json`

```
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
      // Add custom css to bundle.
      "wwwroot/css/CustomCss.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
      // Add custom script to bundle.
      "wwwroot/js/CustomScript.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optinally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Comment: What change have you made to my _layout.cshtml. Can you please elaborate in your answer.

Comment: I am using bower so I dont have to worry about min and bundling. All my css and javascripts are bundle correctly. I have already tested it. As I mention in my question my Jquery works in Development even if I just use bundle version it still works. The problem is when I make the environment Production

Comment: Let's put it this way: Your development environment references all scripts and css individually. Your production environment references only `site.min.css` and `site.min.js`. I haven't been using ASP.NET Core for long, but as far as I can tell, bower is used by default, but you still need to use `bundlesconfig.json` for minification.

Comment: No you dont have to. I am using gulp for bundling.

Comment: The problem is my inline page script are not being compiled in production for some reason.

Comment: Not used gulp before, but unless it mins your css and scripts out to those files it makes no difference. What I asked in my first comments, was where you css classes are? If it's an inline script that used classes from `CustomCss.css` then it will only work if those classes are included in production `site.min.css`. Did you try my suggestion at all? It is only one line of code...

Comment: CustomCss.css has nothing to do with my Jquery.And CustomCss.css  already being included in bundle I have checked. Wiait I willl Update my question I think its confusing you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122372/discussion-between-dave-williams-and-maxspan).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your published version contains your site.min.js in the wwwroot folder. This can be done using "publishOptions" configuration from your project.json :

```
"publishOptions": {
   "include": [
     "wwwroot",
     "Views",
     "appsettings.json",
     "web.config"
   ]
}
```

If your published folder contains your site.min.js. Check if your custom code is below of Jquery framework.

```
gulp.task("min:corejs", function () {
return gulp.src([
        paths.component + 'jquery/dist/jquery.js', 
        'js/customjs.js'
])
    .pipe(concat(paths.corejs))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

});

Comment: Yes I do have site.min.css

Comment: check if your minification concat your custom code after your JQuery file.

Comment: How its suppose to do that. DO you mean my inline jquery code for the page can be attached in the min version.

Comment: When you launch your web site page, does this inline code is displayed in your html source :
      <script src="~/js/min/site.min.js"></script>

Comment: My Inline jquery is not part of the <script src="~/js/min/site.min.js"></script>. Its directly written on the page. Yes I do have reference for the link on the top of the page to access Jquery functions,

Comment: could you paste the error displayed from your console browser.